# Python code to return a phone number in numbers , after giving inputs in words

Tags: python, python-2.7

Yesterday, I was doing one problem where I have to  complete a function which can convert a phone number in numbers after given input in words, I have used `s.replace()` to do that, and modifier also. Since this question was there in hackerrank problem I cant provide complete code, since test is over now and the page is no longer available. How can I use those modifiers as well,
like "two three four double two triple 3" will print 23422333?

```
def getPhoneNumber(s):
    s.replace("Zero" "0")
    s.replace("one" "1")
    ...


modifier = {
    "double": 2,
    "triple" : 3,
}
```

Comment: Use a loop and a dict. Then apply `.replace` in that loop.

Comment: Also, avoid learning Python 2.7, but learn (with) a recent Python 3 version instead. Python 2 is not supported anymore, and the differences are fairly minimal.

Comment: you have to assign result to variabel `s = s.replace(...)`

Comment: @furas okay as you said actually i have used s.replace to replace the number everytime the program sees an word, and store it into s variable, and  i am thinking that i should store the number in a dictionary i think that should work.

Comment: if you use directory then code can be simpler because you can use `for`-loop to run `replace` for different values. And you can put different words (i.e. French) in dictonary to run it for different language without changing `for`-loop.

Answer (score 2):

```py
d = {'zero':'0','one':'1','two':'2','three':'3','four':'4','five':'5','six':'6','seven':'7','eight':'8','nine':'9'}
mod = {'double':2,'triple':3}

num_word = input('Enter Number In Words').split(' ')

number = ''
m = 1
for a in num_word:
    try:
        m = mod[a.lower()]
        continue
    except KeyError:
        pass
    try:
        number+=d[a.lower()]*m
        m = 1
    except KeyError:
        number+=a.lower()*m
        m = 1
print(number)
```

OUTPUT

```py
IN: double two
OUT: 22

IN: two three four double two triple 3
OUT: 23422333
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
def getPhoneNumber(number):
  to_replace = {"zero":"0", "one":"1", "two":"2", "three":"3", "four":"4", "five":"5", "six":"6", "seven":"7", "eight":"8", "nine":"9"}
  modifiers = {"double":2, "triple":3}
  words = list(map(str.lower, number.split()))
  output = ""
  skip = None

  for index, word in enumerate(words):
    if index == skip:
      continue

    if word in modifiers:
      skip = index + 1
      try:
        output += modifiers[word] * to_replace[words[skip]]
      except:
        pass

    else:
      output += to_replace[word]

  return output

getPhoneNumber("Double One Triple Two Five")
```

Output -

```
112225
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = {'zero':'0','one':'1','two':'2','three':'3','four':'4','five':'5','six':'6','seven':'7','eight':'8','nine':'9'}
multipliers = {'double':2,'triple':3}

def solve(sentence):
    results = []
    sentence = sentence.lower().split()
    repeat = 1
    for word in sentence:
        if word in multipliers:
            repeat = multipliers[word]
        else:
            if word in numbers:
                word = numbers[word]
            results.append(word * repeat)
            repeat = 1
    return ''.join(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw this out there as a variation on other themes:

```
d = {'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4',
     'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'}
mod = {'double': 2, 'triple': 3}

num_word = input('Enter Number In Words: ')

number = []
m = None
for word in map(str.lower, num_word.split()):
    if m:
        number.extend(d.get(word, '') * m)
        m = None
    else:
        if not (m := mod.get(word)):
            number.append(d.get(word))

print(''.join(filter(bool, number)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_to_number(s):
    numbers = {
        'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4',
        'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'
    }
    s = s.lower()
    t = s.split(' ')
    result = ''
    count = 0
    while count != len(t):

        if t[count] == 'double':
                
            result = result + 2 * numbers[t[count+1]]
            count = count + 2
                 
        elif t[count] == 'triple':
                
            result = result + 3 * numbers[t[count+1]]
            count = count + 2
                
        else:
            result = result + numbers[t[count]]
            count = count + 1
        
    return result
```